# FFMPEG Filter_Complex_Script crop by time

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to use FFMPEG's filter_complex_script option to crop a video in different places depending on the time. I have a file that shows the bounding box of where an object should be and have written a text file called "myscript.txt" that has commands as follows:

```
crop=x=125:y=190:w=105:h=98
crop=x=124:y=193:w=106:h=99
crop=x=124:y=194:w=106:h=99
```

My command line call for ffmpeg is

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -filter_complex_script "myscript.txt" -c:v libx264 output.mp4
```

This will run fine and produce an output, but the crop window only uses the first line of the file and does not change over time. Currently I have cropping details at the frame level but I can find a way to make this work by second if there is a solution out there.

I am running FFMPEG version 3.4.1 on windows 10.

Thank you!